# How to synchronize and merge data between android device and google cloud datastore?

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I am developing an app that uses an `SyncAdapter` on the android client to synchronized data with a `Google Cloud Store` (`GCS`) backend.

The adapter is working perfectly. Now my doubt is how to properly design the synchronization/merging algorithm taking into account the following issues:

1. The data stored locally on the device can be modified since the last sync took place.
2. The data stored on `GCS` could have changed since the last sync by another device.

I know how to read/write data from the GCS and manipulate it on the device, but not sure whether there is out-of-the-box functionality to perform this task of if I should implement my own from scratch.

Any example or hint would be really appreciated.

Comment: but is it an actual/current solution? GCS stopped working and is superseded by Google Cloud Platform and Google Cloud Messaging.
I see that there is no free space (less than 1GB for example) for small applications.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution is to mark all changes (records?) with 'modified_date'
and update records only with older modify date. If modify date is newer it means a collision/conflict (someone updated record before you were able to do that) - then, you can overwrite data or discard your changes.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this is by following the example implemented in here:
https://code.google.com/p/jumpnote/

The example is missing the GCS part, but all the merging logic is in there.